# url masking via htaccess and apache for a specific url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following in my httpd.conf file

```
Redirect /example /example/
ProxyPass /example/ http://localhost:1105/file/1
ProxyPassReverse /example/ http://localhost:1105/file/1
```

I have

```
www.website.com/example
```

which I want to change to something else

```
www.website.com/somethingElse
```

Essentially, I don't want to give direct access to www.website.com/example by masking it to a name without meaning.

```
<?php header(Location:www/website.com/example)?>
```

would show to the user in url as

```
www.website.com/somethingElse when loaded.
```

Is there a way to do this so that if the user then copies url

```
www.website.com/somethingElse
```

they don't have access to

```
www.website.com/example
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example$ /somethingElse [L]
```